# appending images to a div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div container, that holds 4 more divs and each of these divs have a header, image and a paragraph tag. What I am making is a game, where when I click on one of the divs, images, the remaining 3 images that were not clicked move to the move to another div section with a class of "enemies". How would I do this without having a bunch of onclick functions for each character?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Week 4 Game</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "assets/css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

        <!-- Added link to the jQuery Library -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js" integrity="sha256-laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "assets/javascript/game.js">    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class = "characters">
    <div class="charContainer">
        <h2 id="c1"></h2>
        <img class="vade" src="assets/images/vader.jpg">
        <p id="c1hp" data-hp = "120"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="charContainer1">
        <h2 id="c2"></h2>
        <img class="skywalker" src="assets/images/luke.jpg">
        <p id="c2hp" data-hp = "100"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="charContainer2">
        <h2 id="c3"></h2>
        <img class="obi" src="assets/images/obiwan.jpg">
        <p id="c3hp" data-hp = "150"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="charContainer3">
        <h2 id="c4"></h2>
        <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png">
        <p id="c4hp" data-hp = "180"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="your">
    <h2>Your Character</h2>
    <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#c1').text("Darth Vader");
        $('#c2').text("Luke Skywalker");
        $('#c3').text("Obi Won");
        $('#c4').text("Darth Maul");
        var health = $('#c1hp').data('hp');
        $('#c1hp').html(health);
        var health = $('#c2hp').data('hp');
        $('#c2hp').html(health);
        var health = $('#c3hp').data('hp');
        $('#c3hp').html(health);
        var health = $('#c4hp').data('hp');
        $('#c4hp').html(health);

        $('.charContainer').on('click', function(){
            var yourCharacter = $(this);
            $('#your').append(yourCharacter);
        });

    });
```

I am trying to move anyone of the `<div>`s `.charContainer`, `.charContainer1`, `.charContainer2`, `.charContainer3` including the header, `<img>` and `<p>` tag inside of it to the `<div>` with id `#your`.

Update: I found a solution by doing a .each function for the charContainer. Instead of having 4 different charContainers, I just all named them the same class and in the .each function, for each of these classes that did not get appended to the chosen character box, i added a class called .foes, so that I can now differentiate between divs that have been "selected" and those that have not.

Comment: I tried just having an onlclick function for each character and a bunch of if elses inside

Comment: You could assign an onclick function to all divs of a class and use `this` to dynamically achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Share some code, so that it will lot easier for others to get to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error was that you have different classes for "charContainer" (1,2,3,4). In your case the event should look like

```
 $('.charContainer, .charContainer1, .charContainer2, .charContainer3').on('click', function(){
```

Also the way you do it - you will add multiple characters clicking on them one after another. How about this:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.charContainer').on('click', function(){
      var yourCharacter = $(this);
      $('#your').empty().append(yourCharacter.clone());
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "characters">
    <div class="charContainer">
        <h2 id="c1">Darth Vader</h2>
        <img class="vader" src="assets/images/vader.jpg">
        <p id="c1hp" data-hp = "120"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="charContainer">
        <h2 id="c2">Luke Skywalker</h2>
        <img class="skywalker" src="assets/images/luke.jpg">
        <p id="c2hp" data-hp = "100"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="charContainer">
        <h2 id="c3">Obi Wan</h2>
        <img class="obiwan" src="assets/images/obiwan.jpg">
        <p id="c3hp" data-hp = "150"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="charContainer">
        <h2 id="c4">Darth Maul</h2>
        <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png">
        <p id="c4hp" data-hp = "180"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="your">
    <h2>Your Character</h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: Okay I will do that, but my previous code works, when I click on the selected on click div class,  but only when I click on the div part of the div. How can I make it so that when I click anywhere inside this div, it will move there. I have an h2 tag, p tag and an image all in this div, but the onclick function wont respond unless I click near the edge of the div box

Comment: Your previous code works only if you click somewhere on the first div, because $('.charContainer') is selecting only the first one. Change the code as I told you and it will work.

Also as you can see from my snippet - it works anywhere you click - the h2, image, somewhere in the blank space around the image. 

You may need to read a bit about even bubbles.